# How to stream the videos stored on google cloud storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-streaming, google-cloud-storage

I have stored videos on google cloud storage browser.  I want to play these videos on my frontend. For that I need the video URL. But the problem is, whenever I navigate to that URL, the file gets downloaded.

What do I need to do to get the streaming video URL of my stored object?

Answer (score 5):

Cloud Storage does support streaming transfers using [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming-downloads#command-line). You can also do do streaming transfers on the backend of your application using the third party [Boto python lib](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-plugin#copying-objects).

But since you want this solution to be implemented with a fronted I'm guessing you are actually looking for a media player.

So, you will need to:

1.- Generate a [SignedUrl](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) of the object (your video):

using gcloud command:

```
gsutil signurl -d 10m Desktop/private-key.json gs://example-bucket/cat.jpeg
```

using python lib:

```py
from google.cloud import storage
import datetime
    
def generate_download_signed_url_v4(bucket_name, blob_name):
    """
    Generates a signed URL for downloading a blob.
    
    Note that this method requires a service account key file. You can not use
    this if you are using Application Default Credentials from Google Compute
    Engine or from the Google Cloud SDK.
    """

    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('key.json')
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    
    url = blob.generate_signed_url(
         # This URL is valid for 15 minutes
         expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
         # Allow GET requests using this URL.
         method='GET'
        )
    
    print('Generated GET signed URL:')
    print(url)
    print('You can use this URL with any user agent, for example:')
    print('curl \'{}\''.format(url))
    return url
    
generate_download_signed_url_v4("example-id", "example.mp4")
```

2.- Initialize an HMTL5 media player with that url:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="video-signedurl.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider the possibility is that the object has not been uploaded with the correct `Content-Type`.  This would cause the browser to download it rather than play it.

Comment: Could you also be able to make the stream seekable? I managed to stream video to frontend but then the users cant seek through the video.

Comment: i have a use case which is similar to netflix, user has to pay and authenticate first before they can watch video on my site. How do I prevent users to download the video file and share with people?

Answer (score 5):

I accomplished this using video.js.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  .video-js {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<video-js controls data-setup="{}">
  <source src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucketName/folderName/recordingName.flv" type="video/flv">
</video-js>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-flash/dist/videojs-flash.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```