# how to get link file from google cloud storage use nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform

I'm try to create a video streaming site using react (client), nodejs (server), mongodb (database) and google cloud storage (for video).

My questions are:

1. how do I import files into GCS from nodejs and get the link, so i can save the link into the DB
2. how stream the videos to client

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no attempt to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than saving the url of the file to Mongodb, it's better to generate a [signed url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#overview). This will give users a temporal access to the file. This way you can control who can access your videos easily. On the other hand, if you don't use this method then you will be forced to make your files public and anyone can access them and I guess that's not what you want.

To generate a signed url check the example bellow

```js
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();
async function generateSignedUrl() {
  // These options will allow temporary read access to the file
  const options = {
    version: 'v2', // defaults to 'v2' if missing.
    action: 'read',
    expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60, // one hour
  };

  // Get a v2 signed URL for the file
  const [url] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename).getSignedUrl(options);

  console.log(`The signed url for ${filename} is ${url}.`);
}
```

Comment: so , if the file video , how can i use the video and send to client , so i can stream the video

Comment: once you get the URL you can follow what's listed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321691/how-to-stream-the-videos-stored-on-google-cloud-storage-bucket