# Stream video objects in Google Cloud Storage in iOS mobile app

Tags: ios, swift, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How can I stream video files I have sitting in Google Cloud Storage on iOS?

If I try to play the video URL in iOS, the whole video gets downloaded and then played. That takes too long. I want to stream the video in 10 second chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Google's Cloud Storage allows you to stream data to mobile making use of [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) and a front-end or an app that serves the content.

> It's really important to first set the right [Content-Type](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#content-type) in your objects of Cloud Storage. If not, the browser will download the file instead of playing it.

This would be the steps for this approach:

1. First you'll need to create the Signed URL of the content you want to serve using gcloud commands:

```
gsutil signurl -d 10m Desktop/private-key.json gs://example-bucket/cat.jpeg
```

Or it can also be done with third party libraries. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321691/how-to-stream-the-videos-stored-on-google-cloud-storage-bucket) other post they show how to do it with python.

2. Serve the result link on the front-end/app you want to present the content. Here is an HTML example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="video-signedurl.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
```